# codeigniter drivers

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am checking the new codeigniter driver feature and stuck in the phase of calling child class function in parent class. Is there any good example and description of it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Here's two:

http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2012/01/forms-with-less-pain-using-ci-drivers

http://www.kevinphillips.co.nz/news/codeigniter-drivers-tutorial/

Driver feature isn't exactly "new" :-)

Comment: Ya i have seen these before but looking for some good and effective description.

Comment: step-by-step usage - don't think you'll find more "good and effective description". prolly just read a few times till you understand